# background-clip : Strange behaviors

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css

I have been experimenting with some css3 features lately and I found some strange behaviours. (I use firefox-nightly 18.0a1 (2012-09-24) and chrome Version 22.0.1229.91 beta)

I wanted to make a circle box with say a black background, and a gradient border say blue to transparent.
So I thought I could use 2 different background and clip one (the black one) on the content-box, to make the blue/transparent one appear on the padding-box remaining out of the content-box.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, black, black), -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgb(0, 102, 204), rgba(0, 102, 204, 0);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, black, black), -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgb(0, 102, 204), rgba(0, 102, 204, 0);
background-clip: content-box, border-box;
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome, but in firefox, the different background clips don't seems to be applied, instead, only the latter one is applied, so both background are cliped the same way, so one can't see the blue/transparent background.

Then, I started to want to put an external border around it, say a thin blue border.
so I added :

```
border: 3px solid blue;
```

Chrome displayed my circle in a very strange way :
Everything was clipped in a circle-shape because of the border-radius, but the content became a square.

I made a jsfiddle to make things clear : http://jsfiddle.net/wUtPX/

Is this some known bugs ?
Should I report them to some bug trackers ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the [MDN specs for background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size). Here they explicitly say that:

> Values for the multiple backgrounds, defined by background-image, may
>   be listed separated by commas

While in [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-clip) specs it's not clear. So maybe it doesn't support multiple values.

Also, the [W3C specs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#layering) don't include background-clip in "Layering Multiple Background Images" how-to. So i guess it *shouldn't* support multiple proprieties, and what Chrome is doing is actually "wrong".

You can probably find a workaround with background-origin (which supports multiple values) and background-size, for example:

```
background-origin: border-box, content-box;
background-size: 100% 100%, 99% 99%;
```